# Django: Show reverse object relationship in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

In the templates page, when I want to cycle through the variables of an object related by a foreign key, I use the set.all function.

For example:

```
{% for object2_info in object1.object2_set.all %}
   {[object2_info.something}}
{% endfor %}
```

What I don't get is how can I do this in reverse?
You would think it would be something like this:

```
{% for object1_info in object2.object1_set.all %}
   {[object1_info.something}}
{% endfor %}
```

but, that's not the case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your model definitions. Let's assume you have the following many-to-many-relationship:

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Here, we can access the entries like in your first example, assuming we pass as `Author` object to our template:

```
{% for entry in author.entry_set.all %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

But there is no `author_set` on `Entry`, because we explicitly named it: `authors`.

```
{% for author in entry.authors.all %}
    {{ author.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more about this in [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#m2m-reverse-relationships).